# Issue with static and dynamic linking with visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm struggling with an issue since several months now I thought I found a solution but apparently not.

I'm working with a third part DLL, this DLL works fine when compiling and linking with it but for a client I need to abstract this DLL by another. This DLL aim is to control some hardware device, let's call it Lib-HW

So using Visual Studio I create a new project to build a DLL, that just call the one from the third part. Compiling the new DLL, let's call it Lib A, works like a charm.

But when testing it in a executable compilation still works fine but when in Runtime I see that Lib-A calls Lib-HW but my hardware doensn't behave as it should (it doesn't power off for example)

So now I tested by compiling Lib-A statically, and then tested it with my executable

And only in this case everything is working has it should. The issue is that my client need a DLL to integrate in his environment

So if any of you guys has already seen that I'm quite a new user of visual studio so I may have miss something I'm compiling the all on a Win32 System and configuring my both project in visual to use multithread (/MT)

Thank you

**EDIT**

Here is the code of my LibA (both CSC_XX function are function from my LibHW)

```
void init() {
    int ret;

    ret = CSC_Open((LPSTR)"COM3");
    printf("ret 0x%04x\n", ret);

    ret = CSC_ResetCSC();
    printf("ret 0x%04x\n", ret);
}
```

Here is my executable

```
int main() {
    init();
}
```

My Dll LibA has no custom configuration I'm using pch and dllmain created by visual studio

Comment: When code compiles and works correctly in some versions and incorrectly in others, this can be a symptom of *undefined behaviour* somewhere in the code. Step 1 is to enable full compiler warnings and deal with every warning. If there are none, look out for array bounds, inadequate size of arrays and memory allocation, incorrect use of `sizeof` on pointers, using pointers to data that has gone out of scope, casts that hide compiler warnings, and so on

Comment: There is probably a lot of things that could be potentially wrong. You should do some debugging of your own and try to narrow down the problem some more.

Comment: Code is exactly the same only way of linking differs. I'm juste writing a wrapper against Lib-HW in my LibA so I just called those function I have no warning when compilling in order to understand what could probably go wrong I remove all of my business code and Lib A is now just a dumb wrapper agains LibHW only thing is that compiling Lib A statically make it works

Comment: If the linking differs then the code differs.

Comment: I've updated with sample code

Comment: DLL's are a 'kind of separate executable', so they don't share all memory areas. I.e. passing a `FILE *` opened in the exec could lead to I/O failure in the DLL unless you used the DLL version of CRT runtime. So try to recompile your code, exec and DLL using the switch `/MD`, for the CRT DLL version, instead of the `/MT` that stands for static CRT version.

Comment: I have just tested that and still behave the same :(

Comment: If the code is exactly the same the problem **must** be in the code interaction. If calling directly from exec the hardware library works, but you can't investigate the issue by yourself, I can only suggest to modify the module definition file of your DLL adding the direct export of functions from the original hardware DLL using `myHwFnc1=hwDll.Hwfnc1;`, in this case you don't need to write the stub functions. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=msvc-160.